# how can I scroll up to see a section with a button? react native & typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want a button to be able to scroll to a section where I have some questions, right now I have this code and if I click the button it doesn't do anything, it doesn't scroll, what am I doing wrong?

I have 3 files that I am using:

**home.tsx (here is the front and here I use the other 2 components(files))**

```
  const scrollRef = useRef<SectionList>(null)

<Questions
 questions={question}
 ref={scrollRef}
/>

<AnotherComponent .... />
.....

 <ButtonCard
   goToQuestions={() => {
    scrollRef.current?.scrollToLocation({ animated: true, itemIndex: 0, sectionIndex: 0, viewOffset: 0 })
   }}
 />
```

**Component(file) Questions.tsx**

**as send component prop "refLic"**

```
interface Props {
 refLic?: React.RefObject<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT>>
}
...
...
  <SectionList
    key='questions'
    ref={refLic}
    renderItem={({ item }) => item}
    sections={[
      {
        title: '',
        data: [
          <List.Section title='Questions' titleStyle={styles.title}>
            <FlatList
              data={questions.body.slice(0, itemsToShow)}
              renderItem={renderItem}
            />
          </List.Section>
        ]
      }
    ]}
  />
```

**Component(file) ButtonCard.tsx**

**as send component prop "goToQuestions"**

```
interface Props {
 goToQuestions: () => void
}
...
...

<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={goToQuestions}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Questions
 questions={question}
 ref={scrollRef}
/>
```

but then in your `Questions` component:

```
interface Props {
 refLic?: React.RefObject<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT>>
}

<SectionList
 key='questions'
 ref={refLic}
 renderItem={({ item }) => item}
/>
```

You're passing the ref as `ref` to `Questions`, but expecting `refLic`? And then passing the `refLic` as `ref` to `SectionList`? Is this a typo?

Also, is the `SectionList` handling the `ref` prop properly? You didn't paste any code for that component.

ALSO, I've always used/seen

```
ref.current.scrollIntoView();
```

I haven't seen scrollToLocation, but that could be totally right - not sure.